# Split rows of data in half

Tags: php, arrays, slice

my array is bellow

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [9] => 6
            [11] => 6
            [12] => 6
            [13] => 6
            [14] => 12
        )
[2] => Array
    (
        [4] => 8
        [8] => 8
        [13] => 13
    )
)
```

And I want output like  below , can someone help how I do this 
i wish always i break array in 2 parts.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
           [1] => Array( [9] => 6
                         [11] => 6 
                       )
            [2] => Array( [12] => 6
                          [13] => 6
                          [14] => 12
                       )
        )

[2] => Array
        (
             [1] => Array( [4] => 8
                           [8] => 8
                           )
             [2] => Array( [13] => 13
                           )
        )
)
```

Comment: Why is it that the first subarray (5 elements) is broken into smaller then bigger halves, but then the second subarray (3 elements) is broken into bigger then smaller halves?  Unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$new= array_map(function($v) {
    $temp = array_chunk($v, 2); // break in chunks of 2
    $final[]= array_shift($temp); // Take the first chunk out
    $second= array();
    foreach($temp as $t) {
        $second = array_merge($second, $t); // merge the rest chunks
    }
    if(!empty($second)) {
        $final[]= $second;
    }
    return $final;
}, $array);
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/517391)

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){

  $lastdata = array_slice($v, 2,NULL,true);
  $firstdata = array_chunk($v,2,true);

  $res[$k]['1'] = $firstdata[0];
  $res[$k]['2'] = $lastdata;

}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [9] => 6
                    [11] => 6
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [12] => 6
                    [13] => 6
                    [14] => 12
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 8
                    [8] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [13] => 13
                )

        )

)
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $a=array('1'=>array('9'=>'6','11'=>'6','12'=>'6','13'=>'6','14'=>'12'),'2'=>array('4'=>'8','8'=>'8','13'=>'13'));
    $res = array();
    foreach($a as $k => $v){

      $lastdata = array_slice($v, 2);
      $firstdata = array_chunk($v,2,true);

      $res[$k]['1'] = $firstdata[0];
      $res[$k]['2'] = $lastdata;

    }

echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

check screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){

  $res[$key][1] = array_slice($value, 0, 2, true);
  $res[$key][2] = array_slice($value,2, null, true);    
}

var_dump($res);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [9] => 6
                    [11] => 6
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [12] => 6
                    [13] => 6
                    [14] => 12
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 8
                    [8] => 8
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [13] => 13
                )
        )
)
```

> Only PHP > 5.2.4 : changelog says: The default value of the length parameter was changed to NULL. A NULL length now tells the function to use the length of array. Prior to this version, a NULL length was taken to mean a zero length (nothing will be returned).

Comment: sir its worked and sir if i want to break this array in two equal bins like array then how i do that